# How do I get the value of the 3rd element of this array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting a bit confused here. I'm able to get all the array values, or just one by specifying the number, but I cant figure out how to get the value of the element called "flag" in the array. I'm new to arrays in general and trying to learn all the terminology, but I cant seem to accomplish what I need. Here is the array:

```
Array
(
[0] ( Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Bag
        [flag] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Screen
        [flag] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => HD
        [flag] => 0
    )

)
```

To get that output, I typed:

```
print_r(array_values($items));
```

If I type (which I understand where this is pulling from):

```
print_r(array_values($items[1]));
```

Then I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => Screen
[2] => 1
)
```

What I need to get is the value of the "flag" (3rd) column in this array. I'm just not sure how to get that value. The array will always be pulling in this order from the mysql database. I basically am trying to do something like this:

```
if ($array[1].[flag]==1){
echo "Flag is true";
}else{
echo "Flag is false";
}
```

I'm just not sure how to specify that 3rd element.

Thanks

Comment: No dots, just brackets, and any string keys must be quoted: `if ($array[1]['flag']==1){`

Comment: Use `$array[1][flag]` not `$array[1].[flag]` Notice the absence of the period in my first example. Also, turn on error reporting because it would have yelled at you about such sillyness.

Comment: Calling `array_values()` has obscured the actual keys of the array. Display the contents without calling that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I didn't realize that! That had been my trouble all along. I had tried the `array_values($items[1]['flag'])` before, not realizing it obscured the keys. After just doing `print_r($items[1]['flag'])` I can see what I need! Thank-you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the third element in the Array of sub-arrays then you do it like this:

```
$thirdItem = $items[2]
```

if from third element you mean the subarray with id = 3 then

```
function getItemByID( $items, $id ) {
   for( $i = 0; $i < count( $items ); $i ++ ) {
      if( $items[$i]['id'] == $id ) return $items[$i];
   }
}

$item = getItemByID( $items, 3 );
```

if from 3rd element you mean value of flag in subarray 3

```
$value = $items[2]['flag'];
```

or

```
$value = $thirdItem['flag']
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Works great! Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`$items` is the (outer) `array` which holds the arrays. Foreach iterates over the arrays contained in the (outer) array. They are assigned to the variable `$item`.
If the value of 'flag' of an array equals 1, then "Flag is true" is echoed, else "Flag is false"

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo $item['flag'] == 1 ? "Flag is true" : "Flag is false";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: please include some description

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a little syntax error `$array[1].["flag"]` can't have a `.` between, should be

```
if ($array[1]["flag"]==1){
echo "Flag is true";
}else{
echo "Flag is false";
}
```

This, should works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example of what you posted in your question. I took the liberty to change the flag of the 2nd and 3rd array, for this example.

```
    $items = array
(
0 => array
    (
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Bag',
        'flag' => 0
    ),
1 => array
    (
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Screen',
        'flag' => -1
    ),
2 => array
    (
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'HD',
        'flag' => 1
    )

);
foreach($items as $item) {
    if(empty($item['flag'])) { 
        echo "Item having ID=".$item['id']." has it's flag turned off\n";
    } else {
        if($item['flag']==1) {
         echo "Item having ID=".$item['id']." has it's flag turned on\n";
        } else {
         echo "Item having ID=".$item['id']." has unacceptable flag value \n";  
        }
        }
    }
```

The above example populates the following:

- Item having ID=1 has it's flag turned off
- Item having ID=2 has unacceptable flag value
- Item having ID=3 has it's flag turned on

You can check it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b04a7d9faae8c0a8d335b6cccdadcc7fbe61f61